# Perl regular expression for a repetitive sentence

Tags: perl, pcre

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches a repetitive pattern.

For example

```
The great eagle flied high flied high.
```

Repeted: `flied high`

```
The call was done at night was done at night.
```

Repeated: `was done at night`

Is there a way to achieve this? I just want the regular expression so that I can use a `grep -P` to filter some files.

```
Found 5 files under folders: home folder, home folder, home folder, home folder, home folder
```

Repeated: `home folder`

```
The query returned this preferences for this user: color black, fried chicken, color black, fried chicken, white shirt, brown color
```

Repeated: `color black,`

In essence, what i wanna do is to find "repetitive sentences" to match against".

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem for yourself? Stack Overflow is a place where programmers can ask their contemporaries for help if they are struggling with a problem. It is not meant to be used as a source of free programming effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just utilize `\1` in a regex to indicate a repeated matched pattern.  I intentionally limitted this regex to only match 2-4 word phrases to limit how hard it'd have to work:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my @phrases = /\b(\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,3})\s+\1/g) {
        print "$_\n" for @phrases;
    }
}

__DATA__
The great eagle flied high flied high.
The call was done at night was done at night.
```

**Outputs**

```
flied high
was done at night
```

Comment: to match anything combination more than 4 word phrases, how it would be?

Comment: the use of `{1,3}` indicates 1-3 additional words after the first word.  If you wanted to increase the count, you could there.  I'd recommend that you set some upper limit though, even if it is an arbitrarily high limit.  Or if you really don't want an upper limit, you can just use `+` which indicates one or more.

Comment: Yes. I think with plus sign is just what i need. Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's second example, where the phrase is repeated only after intermediate text. The problem needs to be defined much more precisely before any code can be written.

Comment: @Borodin Actually, given the nature of his question relates to how to search for a repeated expression, the answer is ultimately backreferences `\1` regardless of the specific implementation details or revised specification.  I agree, he would get more benefit out of these forums if he put more effort into his questions in advance, but I would say that I demonstrated an appropriate level of effort in return for what he showed.

Comment: I believe it can be very counter-productive to imply that a highly ambiguous question has an “answer”.

Comment: Even if we prosume this question may fall into the [`XY Problem`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) category, there is still typically an "answer" for Y even if that's not what the OP fully needs.   However, I did take the time to check the habits of this poster, and he has often asked these types of regex questions, so I trusted that he could adapt my "answer" even if he potentially did not share specifications with us that would otherwise be relevant.  *He appears to have agreed.*  Either way, I laud your efforts in trying to clarify a potentially ambiguous questions.

Comment: In the end his question was just "Is there a way to achieve this?".  The answer to that is "yes", and the rough example demonstrates that.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined your question very well. As it stands you could write

```
my $s = 'The great eagle flied high flied high.';
print qq{"$1"\n} if $s =~ /(.+)\1/;
```

**output**

```
" flied high"
```

but then, if you apply your second string

```
my $s = 'The call was done at night was done at night.';
print qq{"$1"\n} if $s =~ /(.+)\1/;
```

**output**

```
"l"
```

So the solution depends on the dataset that you have. If you can define your problem more tightly then we can help you better.